# How to use DatePickerDialog to set start and end date?

Tags: android, kotlin, datepickerdialog

In my Activity, I have 2 TextViews. The user can tap on these TextViews to set a start and end date. I'm using a DatePickerDialog that gets shown when the TextViews are tapped.

My code so far:

```
class DatePickerFragment: DialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val c = Calendar.getInstance()
        val year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)
        val month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
        val day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        return DatePickerDialog(activity, activity as DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener, year, month, day)
    }
}
```

```
class ReportsActivity : AppCompatActivity(), DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    override fun onDateSet(view: DatePicker?, year: Int, month: Int, dayOfMonth: Int) {
        val c = Calendar.getInstance()
        c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month)
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth)
        val dateString = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL).format(c.time)

        // need someway to detect if this is for startDate or endDate
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_report)

        startDateTextView.setOnClickListener {
            val datePicker = DatePickerFragment()
            datePicker.show(supportFragmentManager, "start")
        }

        endDateTextView.setOnClickListener {
            val datePicker = DatePickerFragment()
            datePicker.show(supportFragmentManager, "end")
        }
    }
}
```

I need some way to detect if the user opened the DatePickerDialog from the startDateTextView or the endDateTextView so that I can set the corresponding TextView's text accordingly.

Comment: i think using setOnClickListener to check, it solve your problem.

Comment: You can pass values to the DatePickerFragment, like DatePickerFragment(from:Int) this.

Answer (score 0):

You can set DateListner on textView onClicklistner.

```
override fun onDateSet(view: DatePicker?, year: Int, month: Int, dayOfMonth: Int) {
    val c = Calendar.getInstance()
    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month)
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth)
    val dateString = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL).format(c.time)

    // need someway to detect if this is for startDate or endDate
    updateDisplay();
    updateTextView();
}

private void updateDisplay() {
    ((TextView) touchedView).setText(
        new StringBuilder()
                .append(pad(dayOfMonth)).append(".")
                .append(pad(month)).append(".")
                .append(pad(year)));
}

private void updateTextView() {
    ((EditText) touchedView).setText(
        new StringBuilder()
                .append(pad(dayOfMonth)).append(".")
                .append(pad(month)).append(".")
                .append(pad(year)));
}
```

In Your Fragment add dateListener

```
     DateListener dateListener = new DateListener(getActivity());

     textView.setOnClickListener(dateListener);
```

Also you can see [Getting data from a DatePickerDialog to a fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21443109/getting-data-from-a-datepickerdialog-to-a-fragment)